# error while passing files in lame to convert wav into mp3 using sed

Tags: bash, sed

```
ls -1 | xargs --verbose -I{} basename {} \
    | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' \
    | xargs -I{} lame {}.* {}.wav
```

Using this code to convert all the `wav` files in the folder to `mp3` throws a error:

```
xargs : lame : No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.wav" -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0/\.wav/\.mp3}' {} \;
```

find - will recursively find for a file type starting current directoy with name like *.wav
-exec will move file with .wav extension to .mp3.

Comment: this just moves the file, but I would like to convert the file using sox or lame

Comment: @MaheshwarSelvakumar Then just switch `mv` to `lame`

Comment: You should really add `-maxdepth 1`, since there is no mention of traversing any deeper than 1 level in the question.

Answer (score 0):

why not a loop instead of multiple xargs ?

```
LameApp="/YourAppPath/lame.exe"

ls | while read WavFileWExt
 do 
   "${LameApp}" "${WavFileWExt%.*}.mp3" "${WavFileWExt}"
 done
```

Comment: `-1` is redundant when piping, parsing `ls` is `always` error prone, quote your variables/brace-expansion, and add `.mp3` to end of the second argument (without wav) to lame

Comment: sorry, copy older test version. I put the latest one and remove the -1 (habit to use other option)